# Delete record from multiple tables when using a View CakePHP 2.8.x

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.8.x and i'm looking for a way to delete records from 2 tables with 1 delete action.

I created a View from 3 tables: visitors, guests and registrations. These tables are connected through visitor_id.

In the Visitor Model i added the View in `$useTable`. Now when i press delete on, for example, visitor 1, i want to delete the records from  visitor 1's guests and registrations tables and keep the visitor information in the visitor's table

I did found `$this->Visitor->delete($id)`, but what parameters do i need to add to this function, so i can delete just the records from the guests and registrations tables?

If i need to give more information, i'm happy to help! Thx in advance

Update: The tables are associated. These are the models:

Visitor:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Guest' => array(
        'className' => 'Guest',
        'foreignKey' => 'visitor_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'exclusive' => false,
    ),
    'Registration' => array(
        'className' => Registration',
        'foreignKey' => 'visitor_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'exclusive' => false,
    ),

);  

public $belongsTo = array(

);
```

Registration:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Visitor' => array(
        'className' => 'Visitor',
        'foreignKey' => 'visitor_id',
    ),

);
```

Guest:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Visitor' => array(
        'className' => 'Visitor',
        'foreignKey' => 'visitor_id',
    ),
```

Comment: Are these three tables associated? If so, please show their association code in the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's the `deleteAll()` function in cake 2 (see the [**cookbook**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html#deleteall))

you have to pass to the function an array of conditions. In your case you want to delete all the `Guests` that have `visitor_id = $id` (the same for `Registration`).

```
$this->Visitor->Guest->deleteAll(array('visitor_id' => $id));

$this->Visitor->Registration->deleteAll(array('visitor_id' => $id));
```

this will delete all the `Guests` and the `Registrations` of the `Visitor` without touching the `Visitor` itself

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I thought deleteAll will delete everything associated with that id (including other tables), but it justs deletes all records in te table containing that id :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try it,its worked for me

```
public function your_action($id=null){
    $this->MainMdel->ConnectedModel1->deleteAll(array('ConnectedModel_id' => $id));
    $this->MainMdel->ConnectedModel2->deleteAll(array('ConnectedModel_id' => $id));
    }
```